# Unable to attach to application ... The format of the PE module is invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Im trying to debug a silverlight app inside it's web project.

Any time I run the debugger I receive the message:

```
Unable to attach to application 'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (PID: 8412) using '[PC-NAME]'.  The format of the PE module is invalid.
```

Edit: I've tried removing the SUO files, clean and build - nothing will make this error go away, and googling the phrase "the format of the PE module only pulls up THIS question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you recently install Visual Studio Update 2? Someone else who had this same problem (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/5682aee9-942b-4c13-9986-178d1b84ea55/) fixed the issue by uninstalling Update 2.

Comment: I actually resolved it by applying the pre-release update and restarting the system.

Comment: You can get it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188